# How do I profile a method from URL that is causing issues in my program?

Tags: java, multithreading, profiling

I have written a piece of software in Java that checks if proxies are working by sending a HTTP request using the proxy. It sends requests in parallel, with over 100 threads running using a ThreadPool.

The following method is used to check an individual proxy:

```
public boolean isWorkingProxy() {
    //Case of an invalid proxy
    if(proxyPort == -1) {
        return false;
    }

    HttpURLConnection con = null;

    //Perform checks on URL
    //IF any exception occurs here, the proxy is obviously bad.
    try {
        URL url = new URL(this.getTestingUrl());
        //Create proxy
        Proxy p = new Proxy(this.testingType, new InetSocketAddress(this.proxyIp, this.proxyPort));
        //No redirect
        HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
        //Open connection with proxy
        con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(p);
        //Set the request method
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        //Set max timeout for a request.
        con.setConnectTimeout(this.timeout);
        con.setReadTimeout(this.timeout);
    } catch(MalformedURLException e) {
        System.out.println("The testing URL is bad. Please fix this.");
        return false;
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid request type provided (Not GET / POST / Valid type)");
        return false;
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Failed to open connection with url using proxy.");
        return false;
    }

    try(
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            ) {

        //read text response
        String inputLine = null; StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }


        //A valid proxy!
        return con.getResponseCode() > 0;

    } catch(Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The following code is how I initiate threads:

```
Deque<String> proxies = DB.getProxiesToCheck();
while(proxies.isEmpty() == false) {
    try {
        String[] split = proxies.pop().split(":");

        //Submit every check for this proxy
        //There are a total 7 checks right now.
        for(int i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) {
            executor.submit(new RunnableProxyRequest(split[0], split[1], checks[i]));
        }

    } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        continue;
    }
    //Wait 50ms before each proxy
    Thread.sleep(50);
}
```

Now: the CPU usage gets pretty high at some points, and I have tried profiling it using JVisualVM. I have the following results:

[image: JVisualVM profiler image]

It states that I have "Abdandoned connection cleanup thread", however my code uses a try with resources to open the `HttpURLConnection`'s input stream, and I cannot find any instances where I have left an open connection. I do not open any other streams apart from the ones in the method.  Moreover, it looks like parseURL (a method used in Java's URL object) is consuming 100% of my CPU time.

Do note that it updates an SQL database to report whether a proxy is working.The updating of the MySQL database is `synchronized()`.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

**EDIT**

I added a `Thread.sleep(50);` before sending each proxies checks into the exectuor service (evident in the code above) I also added the argument `-XX:+UseParallelGC` to my command line. It seems to last longer, but after a few hours the CPU usage still goes up very high and the program crashes.

Answer (score 0):

The outputStream should also be closed.
Making 100+ connections at the same time costs CPU resource indeed, especially when most proxies are available.

Comment: Which outputStream? I have no outputStreams in my code?